# how to use a flash movie as a background image of a vb.net form

Tags: vb.net, flash, background

I want to put a flash movie in my vb.net form as a form background. i want controls like buttons and labels on top of that flash movie. If this is possible then please provide a step by step answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have flash installed.

Right click on the visual studio toolbox > choose items  .. when the dialog appears click on the COM components tab and scroll till you find the "Shockwave Flash Object" , tick the checkbox to add it to your toolbox.

Drag the control from your toolbox to your form ... set its "Movie" property to absolute url of your flash swf file.

you can now drop controls on top of the shockwave flash control (your flash movie host).

You might need to drag the control to fill up the available form size.

To disable the flash menu you could put a Panel above the Shockwave Flash Object and make the panel transparent ... but the usual way won't work properly.
Code below is gotten from this [link](http://www.fsmpi.uni-bayreuth.de/~dun3/archives/creating-a-transparent-panel-in-net/108.html)

```
   public class TransparentPanel : Panel
    {
        public TransparentPanel()
        {
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
                createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
                return createParams;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do not paint background.
        }
    }
```

Add that to your project and make the panel you add an instance of this class you'll get a transparent overlay on the shockwave flash object that disables the right click on any other mouse events.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it necessary to provide a web URL or is it OK if I point it to the subfolder/filename.swf

Comment: there is one problem , my flash movie file is long in width , so when run the app, flash automatically makes the remaining portion white making it look square. also how do i disable the right click on the flash movie.

Comment: You can use either a local url or a web url. i'm not sure if you can disable the right click .. but u can reduce the number of items by setting the "Menu" property to false. i'm currently investigating the right click disable issue.

Comment: @subanki I seriously doubt an easy way exists to completely disable right mouse click on the control.

Comment: I haven't worked with .Net forms for long, but if you can place a transparent object of some sort above the Flash (and beneath the other controls), that may be a way to avoid the Flash right click menu. That is, if there is no need to interact with the Flash, if it is only for a visual effect.

Comment: @Lars .. your comment provided a solution ... editing my answer and adding it shortly ... Thanks

Comment: @Lars thats exactly what I was thinking too :)

Comment: @scartag how do I make the panel an instance of the main form's class? can u elaborate it ? I  don't know much about vb.net

Comment: @subanki .. i just realized u use vb.net .. will create a sample in vb.net and send it to u if u want .. my email is scartag at gmail dot com ... mail me and i'll send u the sample.

Comment: @scartag.. i am happy to email u ... i will email u now

Comment: @scartag Which version of vb.net are you using